# Export tangent space FBX

Tags: export, file-format

I'm trying to get the tangent space information in my exported files, but it never seems to appear. I have a simple model with a UV mapping and export to FBX. The resulting file has no mention of tangents.

The [FBX reference](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_FBX) indicates that tangents are supported, so perhaps something is wrong with my model.

How can I get an export to contain the tangents and bitangents?